# How do I combine 2 sets of data into one UITableview

Tags: arrays, swift, uitableview, merge

I want to know how I can combine 2 sets of data into one table view

```swift
    var myFirstData = ["Hello", "Hi"]
    var mySecondData = ["Goodbye", "Bye"]
```

And for the `cellForRowAt`, `numberOfRowsInSection` and the `trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt` what should I put to detect which array I'm using

*If you can, can you give me an example project*

Comment: Datasource needs to be one array. So how about `var dataArray = myFirstData + mySecondData`?

Comment: I recommend you read up about similar question about using UITableView. Maybe look at what is a "delegate / datasource". In short you need to implement those method so UITableView knows about what to display for each cell ("row") and how many rows there are etc.

Comment: I do not want to combine the arrays

Comment: @AshwinPaudel how else will the tableview work? Your original arrays won't be affected if you do `var dataArray = myFirstData + mySecondData`, if you are concerned about that

Comment: @aheze Thanks!! Could you make an answer, I will mark it correct

Comment: You will get more reputation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should always use one array of data for table views. This makes it easy to keep track of, as you can just return the object at the requested `indexPath.row` to the datasource.

If you have 2 arrays of data that you want to display, it will be much easier to combine them into one...

```
var combinedData = myFirstData + mySecondData
```

...then feed the tableview that combined array. Your original arrays will be unaffected.

Here is a sample with `cellForRowAt`, `numberOfRowsInSection` and `trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt` implemented.

```
class TableCell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var myFirstData = ["Hello", "Hi"]
    var mySecondData = ["Goodbye", "Bye"]
    var combinedData = [String]()
    
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        combinedData = myFirstData + mySecondData /// set combinedData (will not affect myFirstData or mySecondData)
        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.delegate = self
    }
}

extension ViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return combinedData.count /// simply return the count of the entire combinedData array
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TableCellIdentifier", for: indexPath) as! TableCell
        let textAtRow = combinedData[indexPath.row] /// also get what to display from combinedData
        cell.label.text = textAtRow
        return cell
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UISwipeActionsConfiguration? {
        let textAtRow = combinedData[indexPath.row]
        
        let title = "Capitalize"
        
        let action = UIContextualAction(style: .normal, title: title, handler: { (_,_,_) in
            
            let uppercasedText = textAtRow.uppercased()
            
            /// Update data source when user taps action
            self.combinedData[indexPath.row] = uppercasedText
            
            /// if you want to modify the original arrays
            if let firstIndex = self.myFirstData.firstIndex(of: textAtRow) { /// get first index of text at this row, if exists
                self.myFirstData[firstIndex] = uppercasedText /// set the text to the new text
            }
            if let firstIndex = self.mySecondData.firstIndex(of: textAtRow) {
                self.mySecondData[firstIndex] = uppercasedText
                
            }
            
            self.tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
            
            print("Combined: \(self.combinedData), myFirstData: \(self.myFirstData), mySecondData: \(self.mySecondData)")
        })
        
        action.image = UIImage(systemName: "textformat")
        action.backgroundColor = .blue
        let configuration = UISwipeActionsConfiguration(actions: [action])
        return configuration
    }
}
```

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

[*Repo on GitHub*](https://github.com/aheze/TwoSetTableView/tree/main)